# Rule for Finding Largest Possible Perimeter

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Some months ago I was given a high-school level maths question that made me wonder if there was a definitive principle for finding the shape of largest perimeter given a set of dots. The question was worded something like the following; Given a 5 by 5 array of points, and using only straight lines, form a polygon with the highest possible perimeter. I understood I would have to use as many and as space-efficient diagonals as possible to maximize my possible perimeter, but couldn't find a rule or certain answer as to the upper bound. So A) What would be the highest possible perimeter shape (I believe I found somewhere around 40, but others found higher) and B) What constant rule can be followed to find the largest possible perimeter for a definite area. I was considering writing a program to brute-force all possible shapes, but wasn't sure if that was even feasible in a reasonable finite time.

EDIT: Polygon must touch all points in the array and can not self-intersect. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: Does your polygon have to be convex? Does it have to be non-self-intersecting? Have you tried smaller problems, like 2 by 2, 2 by 3, 3 by 3?

Comment: For a general set of points:

The answer is trivial for convex - take the perimeter of the convex hull - and allowing self-intersection gives a problem that's very close to the travelling salesman problem (although if you are considering the points as being in Euclidean space, it would have some restrictions on the distances, effectively "reversing" the Euclidean travelling salesman problem).

Comment: Thanks for including the extra information, Morriel. Now: have you tried smaller problems? And why does the title ask for largest area, when the body asks for largest perimeter?

Comment: The question for *minimum area* has been explored in this MO question: "[Given a set of 2D vertices, how to create a minimum-area polygon which contains all the given vertices?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/192114/6094)." That problem is NP-hard. I suspect yours is also, but I don't have a reference.

Comment: For arbitrary point sets in the plane, this sounds like the "longest noncrossing TSP" problem. It was studied by Alon, Rajagopalan, Suri in the paper "Long non-crossing configurations in the plane" who give (IIRC) a constant-approximation. The version with grid points might be easier of course.

Comment: Consider also "The Shoelace Problem", by J H Halton, in Math. Intelligencer 17.

Comment: Is it known how many such polygons there are?  That could tell us whether brute force is feasible.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The best lowerbound on the number of *polygonizations* of $n$ points is ~$4.6^n$.

Comment: Well, $4.6^{25}$ isn't *that* large.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, minimizing the area will do nothing in this case (!) -- by Pick's theorem, any polygon on these vertices will have an area of 23/2.

Comment: @NateEldredge the number of polygons that can be drawn using all and only the vertices of an nxn square would be a good candidate for the OEIS, but I couldn't find it there.  The sequence begins 0,1,1, but even n=4 is hard to calculate.

Answer (score 4):

This gives a perimeter of $11 + 3\sqrt{2}  + 7\sqrt{5}  + 2\sqrt{10} 
 + 2\sqrt{13} \simeq 44.43$.
[image: Comfiguration through 5x5 points]

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this is optimal?

Comment: It's the best I found via trial and error.  I think sqrt(13) is the longest possible side length, and that there can be at most 2 sides of that length.  I'd be interested to see the results of the algorithms in the comments.

Comment: I don't think sqrt (13) is the longest possible side length - you can start by drawing a diagonal of length sqrt (18) from one of the corners and complete it to a closed circuit, and even include two sides with length sqrt (13) adjacent to it. Of course, the resulting polygon need not be longer overall.

Comment: @VictorProtsak, I would count the diagonal of length sqrt(18) as three sides rather than one, since it goes through the corner plus three other vertices.

Comment: Fair enough. There are also polygons with three sides of length sqrt (13), although for my best example of this type, the total perimeter, 11+6sqrt (2)+4sqrt (5)+sqrt (10)+3sqrt (13), is less than for the one you have constructed.