# Complexity of existence of simple polygonalization with prescribed area?

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-geometry, polygons

This is a followup on my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328229/what-is-known-about-this-tsp-variant). Fekete proved the NP-completeness of deciding the existence of simple polygonalization with minimum (or maximum) enclosed area (simple polygonalization  is a closed chain of straight line segments that does not cross itself).

I am interested in the complexity of this problem:

Input: Set of points $S$ on integer 2D grid and a rational number $A$

Question: Is there a polygonalization that has enclosed area $A$?

> Is this problem still NP-complete?

The area $A$ is given as a pair of integers (represented in unary)

Fekete, Sándor P. ["On simple polygonalizations with optimal area."](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FPL00009492#page-1) *Discrete & Computational Geometry* **23**.1 (2000): 73-110

Comment: One possible idea: The max possible area is $A_h$, the area of the hull. Imagine an MST rooted on the hull incorporating all interior points. Fatten the MST minimally. The hull with this thickened MST seems like the max possible area of any polygonization. If you input this as $A$, it would seem you'd have to solve the max-area problem to know if $A$ is achievable.